# Why is the output ending the line early and filling every empty spaces with setfill instead of creating a line with it?

Tags: c++, cout, setw

Im trying to create a ling of the special character "="

Output I want

```
Name====================
Horace Horsecollar    56.00  12.50  700.00  210.00  10  480.00
Eleven Thirty         34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50
Victoria Elven        34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50
```

but the output here is filling all empty spaces in the output with "="

Output I'm getting

```
Name
==Horace Horsecollar====56.00  12.50  700.00  210.00  10  480.00
Eleven Thirtyman======34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50
Victoria Elven========34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50

Employees.push_back(new Employee("Horace Horsecollar", 56, 12.5));
Employees.push_back(new Employee("Eleven", 34, 12.5));
Employees.push_back(new Employee("Victoria Elven", 34, 12.5));
```

Code

```
cout << "Name" << setw(20) << setfill('=') << endl;

for (vector<Employee *>::iterator i = Employees.begin(); i < Employees.end(); i++) {
  cout << (*i)->getName() 
  
  << setw(27 - ((*i)->getNamesize()) ) << fixed << setprecision(2) 
  << (*i)->getHoursWorked() 
  << "  " << (*i)->getHourlyRate() 
  << "  " << (*i)->getGrossPay()
  << "  " << (*i)->getTaxes()
  << "  " << 10
  << "  " << (*i)->getNetPay() << "\n";
```

I'm really really confused, there's something about cout that I don't understand, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Have you tried `setfill(' ')` once you no longer need to add `=`?

Comment: You need to make `setfill('=')` right before the "Name", then `setfill(' ')` to make rest of the output use space rather than '='

Comment: Do you want exactly 20 `=` or 20 additional `=`? In the later case you don't really need `setw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put formatters before the text.

```cpp
         cout << setw(21) << setfill('=') << left << "Name" << setfill(' ') << endl;
```

The `left` keyword means that the following text will be lined up on the left side of the 21-character column. The fill characters will go on the right.

This also goes for the first part of your loop where the name is printed. The entire point of `setw()` is that you don't need to deal with the length of the data in the column.

```cpp
for (vector<Employee *>::iterator i = Employees.begin(); i < Employees.end(); i++) {
  cout << setw(22) << left << (*i)->getName() 
       << fixed << setprecision(2) << (*i)->getHoursWorked() 
       << "  " << (*i)->getHourlyRate()
       << "  " << (*i)->getGrossPay()
       << "  " << (*i)->getTaxes()
       << "  " << 10
       << "  " << (*i)->getNetPay() << "\n";
}
```

Here, the name will be put on the left side of a 22-character column. The rest of the space is taken up by spaces because of the call to `setfill(' ')` after the Name heading.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the comments, they really helped out

I was missing a "=" at the very end of the line to make it complete

```
cout << "Name" << setw(17) << setfill('=') << "=" << setfill(' ') << endl;
```

output

```
Name=================
Horace Horsecollar    56.00  12.50  700.00  210.00  10  480.00
Eleven Thirty         34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50
Victoria Elven        34.00  12.50  425.00  127.50  10  287.50
```